# Using :limit and :order in the associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way i can limit the results of an associated model?

This what i was trying to do :

```
<ul>
        <% account.logins.slice(0,5).sort_by(&:login_date).reverse.each do |login| -%>
          <li><%=h login.login_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")%></li>
        <% end -%>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get the last five logins of the account. I cant seem to do it with account.logins(:limit=>5)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
account.logins.find(:all, :limit => 5, :order => 'login_date desc')
```

Comment: Don't use find(:all). It will be deprecated with Rails 3.0.

Comment: @theWillCole this was answered while rails 3 was still in beta/rc

Comment: @Faisal my bad; I should have noticed the date and pointed out that it's deprecated now. I can't undo the downvote unless the answer is edited, so I gave you an upvote on the comment.

Answer (score 3):

or even shorter:

```
account.logins.all(:limit => 5, :order => 'login_date DESC')
```

=)

Comment: I think this is deprecated in the current version of rails. You should chain the "limit" and "order" methods instead of passing them as arguments to the "all" method.

Comment: if u noticed, the above is answered on 19 Apr 2010... so there's little doubt that it's deprecated ;-)